# How often can you reuse coomassie stain?

Tags: gel-electrophoresis

I usually heat to boil in the microwave, and stain for 12 minutes. How often can I reuse this buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there's a lot of methanol in Coomassie stain, a significant amount would probably evaporate off each time you microwave it. Therefore, it'd be probably a good idea not to reuse it because (1) you're losing methanol, and (2) the concentration of everything else is thrown off.

Why do you boil the stain? I just pour mine at RT right on the gel and it works fine.

Comment: Doesn't heating it up make it stain faster?   Also, labs I've worked in have done both: reuse and not.  My impression is that you can reuse some of it, but it's best if mixed 50/50 with fresh stain.  But of course, this is all lab folklore.  I'd be curious to know if there has ever been a systematic study of whether/how much re-use affects results.

Comment: I've never boiled it and it always stained my gels fine in 10-15 minutes. (Plus it takes a few minutes to boil anyways... and sniffing those methanol vapours isn't exactly good for you...)

Comment: And after I've stained the gel, I just pour it back into the container. I've used the same bottle of stain for 2+ years. Works like a charm.